# Read job name from bash script parameters in SGE

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, qsub

I am running Sun Grid Engine for submitting jobs, and I want to have a bash script that sends in any file I need to run, instead of having to run a different `qsub` command with a different bash file for each of the jobs. I have been capable of generating output and error files that share the name of the input file, but now I am struggling with setting a different name for each file. My approach has been the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -N $1
#
python -u $1 >/output_dir/$1.out 2>/error_dir/$1.error
```

This way, running `qsub send_to_sge.sh foo` executes the program, and creates the files `foo.error` and `foo.out` with the errors and printouts, respectively. However, the job appears with the name `$1` in the SGE queue. Instead, I would like to have `foo` as the job name. Is there any way to achieve what I am seeking?